# SortedList<Key, Value>: Error while changing the values inside a loop, while looping through the list / Unity, C#

Tags: c#, loops, linq, unity-game-engine, sortedlist

I am having trouble programming this feature for a game i am making in Unity. I use a SortedList<GameObject, float> to store the interactable objects my player enter trigger with, and their distance from him. I want him to be able to interact only with one object, the one closest to him. For that reason i run through the list and update the float value of the keys with the new distance each frame, and then set the object's canInteract bool to true, if its the one in index 0 of the list, meaning the closest to the player.

This works, but Unity throws me an error saying that i am altering the values while it is still iterating through the KeyValue pairs, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

My code is the following:

```
public SortedList<GameObject, float> interactablesInRange = new SortedList<GameObject, float>();

public void CheckForInteractableDistance()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<GameObject, float> interactable in interactablesInRange)
        {
            interactablesInRange[interactable.Key] = DistanceChecker(gameObject, interactable.Key);
            Debug.Log(interactable.Key + " distance from player: " + interactable.Value);

            if (interactablesInRange.IndexOfValue(interactable.Value) == 0)
            {
                interactable.Key.GetComponent<WeaponPickup>().canInteract = true;
            }
            else
            {
                interactable.Key.GetComponent<WeaponPickup>().canInteract = false;
            }
        }
    }


public float DistanceChecker(GameObject fromObj, GameObject toObj)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(fromObj.transform.position, toObj.transform.position);

        return distance;
    }
```

I am trying to find a way to avoid that error, while still doing the same thing. I was suggested i can maybe do that with LINQ, but i dont know how to use LINQ or if this would fix the issue since i still have to change the value while iterating through the list

Comment: One approach is to effectively take a copy of the current items and iterate through that - change `interactablesInRange` to `interactablesInRange.ToList()` in your loop. As an aside, it looks like you're using the *old* value in your loop after you've updated it.

Comment: I will try that. Thnx for the reply. How would I use the new value though? I thought I was doing that.

Comment: The new value is presumably returned by `DistanceChecker(gameObject, interactable.Key)`. The old value in `instance.Value` will not change, it's essentially a snapshot. It may be clearer if your loop just iterated the keys - `interactablesInRange.Keys.ToList()` - given you don't need the old value.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thinking about it now i can put the GameObjects my player collides with in a normal `List<GameObject>`, and have a variable to store the `distance` from the player on the `WeaponPickup` script, and then itterate through that list, update the distance with the `DistanceChecker` function and sort that list by looking at the distance from player variable. And after the list is sorted i get the first element of that list and activate `canInteract` bool on that.

That would go around the problem with the sorted list, at least this is how i understand it.

Comment: Actually i just found that i can do 
` MyGameObjectList = MyGameObjectList.OrderBy (e => e.GetComponent<MyComponent>().MyComponentMember).ToList (); ` using LINQ so i ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after reviewing the comments i realised that it was not nessecary to use a SortedList in that case and that the way i used it before was incorrect.

After a bit more research online i found out a comment in this thread (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1408498/sorting-a-list-based-of-a-variable.html) that basically answers my question and does what i want to do using a simple LINQ expression in one line of code!

So case is solved! In case you want to do something similar i post the code below:

```
private void SortByDistance()
    {
        foreach (GameObject interactable in interactablesInRange)
        {
            interactable.GetComponent<WeaponPickup>().distanceFromPlayer = DistanceChecker(gameObject, interactable);
        }

        interactablesInRange = interactablesInRange.OrderBy(e => e.GetComponent<WeaponPickup>().distanceFromPlayer).ToList();

    }
```

After that i just check in each interactables script if the interactable is the GameObject in index [0] of the list, and if it is i set canInteract bool to true.